# Running Mac app in batch Mode from Launch Agents with KeepAlive

Tags: macos, shell

I am really in need of some help with Launch Agents Mac, basically what I would like to know if there is any way of specifying how the programs kept alive. So for my case, I have my app TEST.app on my desktop... I have my .plist file which specifies that I want it to be kept alive etc, but what I would like it to do is when it does launch the app it requires it to be done like my image linked below. Thanks. [So with -batchmode and -nographics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb3NY.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your agent with arguments, you need to add an array of them to your .plist file for `ProgramArguments` key:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>-batchmode</string>
    <string>-nographics</string>
</array>
```

More details can be found in Apple's [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001762-104142) documentation.